# How to calculate Percentile of given value based on other values and percentile

Tags: statistics, algorithms, median, percentile

I have a problem related to a formula and I need help from all of you. It may use some statistics formula to solve the problem. Your help would be appreciated.

===========

We have following values (Percentile and respected values)

3% :——————: 7.7999999999999998

15% :——————: 8.5999999999999996

50% :——————: 9.5999999999999996

85% :——————: 10.800000000000001

97% :——————: 11.800000000000001

Now we need to find the percentile of given value with respect to above values

Suppose Given Value -> 8.2 Then what will be the percentile of 8.5 (It should be less than 15% and greater than 3%)?

Then what will be the percentile of 10.0 (It should be less than 85% and greater than 50%)?

Comment: As long as you do not know anything more about the distribution of the data, you may interpolate linearly to get estimates for other pecerntiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intervals you suggest are reasonable. Unless you have additional information or want to make assumptions, they are the best you can do.

I suppose the information you have is from a sample and you're asking for approximate sample percentiles. Are those supposed to serve as estimates of population percentiles? I assume you don't have access to the entire sample.

You could use the information given in your question  to make a plot of the estimated CDF (as below). If it looks like
the CDF of a known distribution, perhaps try to fit that. Otherwise, use linear
interpolation.

[image]

In this case, the population may be that of a normal distribution. If so, you
can estimate the mean as about 9.65 (median is 9.6, but other quantiles suggest a little higher) and from the quantiles you can deduce that the SD
is about 1.03 or 1.04. Superimposing the CDF of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=9.65,\,\sigma=1.035)$ [heavy blue curve] on the estimated CDF shows a pretty good
match.

```
diff(qnorm(c(.15,.85)))
[1] 2.072867            # spread btw 15th & 85th pctl for NORM(0,1)
2.027/(10.7-8.7)
[1] 1.0135              # rough est of pop SD based on data
```

[image]

If you believe data may have come from this normal distribution, then the
required percentile estimates are 8th percentile for 8.2 and 63rd percentile for 10.
[Computations in R below. In R, `pnorm` is a normal CDF.]

```
pnorm(8.2,9.65,1.035)
[1] 0.08061209          # About 8% of sample below 8.2
pnorm(10,9.65,1.035)
[1] 0.6323803           # About 63% of sample below 10
```

These estimates are in the intervals you suggested. Perhaps they are
more useful than what
you would have gotten by linear interpolation using the estimated (broken line) CDF. I will leave the linear interpolation to you. Results should be
about the same.